# ExpirationError when using Google ML Engine's predict

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use a model deployed to Google ML engine for predictions, but I'm getting an `ExpirationError`, and I don't understand why:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict \                                                                                                               
    --model $MODEL_NAME \
    --version v1 \
    --json-instances \
    test_image.json

{
    "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: ExpirationError(code=StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, details=\"Deadline Exceeded\")"
}
```

The model itself must be fine, since locally it runs without any problems:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict \                                                                    
    --model-dir export \ 
    --json-instances \
    test_image.json

[Expected outputs here]
```

The question seems to be rated to these ones ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152496/gcp-ml-engine-predict-not-work), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323168/expirationerrorcode-statuscode-deadline-exceeded-details-deadline-exceeded?newreg=505e8b49a7a14ca38cb11f99380eea9b)), however I didn't find an answer there (the first one is unanswered, the second seems not to be about a model deployed to ML Engine).

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is because of `gcloud ml-engine predict` being somehow very slow. I tried using a smaller input to the model (which works without an `ExpirationError`), locally it is processed in ~10 seconds, in the cloud it takes around ~1minute 20seconds. So the original `ExpirationError` seems to have been caused by slow processing.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you following a tutorial? What model are you using?

Comment: What `--runtime-version` are you using when creating the version? Can you run `python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)'` on the machine that you are running `local predict` and then use the same version on the service, e.g. if it prints `1.8.0`, pass `--runtime-version=1.8` as a flag.

Comment: Another question: how long does `local predict` take to run (e.g. < 1 sec, 10 secs, 100 secs, etc.)? put `time` in front of the command to see.

Comment: @J.LValtueña I have a model consisting of the VGG up to the last convolutional layer for feature extraction, and a few fully-connected layers on top. The model is in keras and I've been mostly following this example (https://github.com/clintonreece/keras-cloud-ml-engine). The strange thing is that it works locally just fine, and I don't see what could be the difference when using prediction in the cloud.

Comment: @rhaertel80 Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm already using the `--runtime-version` argument (it is 1.8 as you suggested)

Comment: @rhaertel80 `local predict` takes around 12-15 seconds to process an input (an image)

Comment: It seems that the problem is because of `gcloud ml-engine predict` being somehow very slow. I tried using a smaller input to the model (which works without an `ExpirationError`), locally it is processed in ~10 seconds, in the cloud it takes around ~1minute 20seconds. So the original `ExpirationError` seems to have been caused by slow processing, which is the root of the problem

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the slow processing? If so, please can you describe the solution in an answer?

Comment: We're currently investigating some slowness with 1.8. We expect it to be fixed and pushed to prod by the end of this week.

Comment: @ivust do you mind sending your project id, model and version information to cloudml-feedback@google.com in order to help us with verify that our fix will indeed apply to your model?

Comment: @ChristopherP if you also are experiencing problems, same request: please send your project id, model and version information to cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: Also, you're likely going to want a machine with more cores. email cloudml-feedback@google.com to get access to those.